# Why can't we geminate affricates in sentences when talking?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

I read a book which said that if we link affricate sounds when talking, people would misunderstand the meaning of the sentence. But why?

For example:

> "orange juice," the j sound should be pronounced twice.

> "which chair"

1. Why can't we link two affricate sounds?
2. Why does linking two affricate sounds cause misunderstanding?

[Ref](https://pronuncian.com/introduction-to-linking) mentioned the same thing.

> The j sound /ʤ/ and ch sound /ʧ/ are the only affricate sounds in English. In a sequence of identical affricates, no special linking occurs and the sounds are pronounced twice in a row.

Comment: Maybe because affricates are composed of two different sounds (plosives + fricatives). We usually geminate two *similar* sounds when they're next to each other (ba"d d"ay), but when two affricates come next to each other, we get four sounds. /// Orange juice -> [ɒɹɪn d͡ʒ d͡ʒ uːs], there are four sounds [d ʒ d ʒ]... but I don't know.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Thank you. That's what I guess, but I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: I think that the question would be helped by any example of any terminal and starting sound that do fuse and in which one is lost. --- "Peach juice" would become "pea juice", which is a different thing.

Comment: @Greybeard: we don't pronounce two /k/s or /t/s in *stock car* or *last time*. We do pronounce a slightly longer /k/ or /t/, though.

Comment: That book is crazy. Only maybe the most conscientious and pedantic news anchor might pronounce the two distinctly, with great difficulty. And that as a native speaker with years of elocution experience. Which is not to say that an ESL learner shouldn't try to articulate them both because it will lead to a more natural merging.

Comment: @Mitch: I guess most native English speakers are excessively conscientious and pedantic. Listen to [Forvo.com](https://forvo.com/word/orange_juice/). We don't put a pause between *orange* and *juice*, but there are two distinct /d͡ʒ/ sounds.

Comment: @PeterShor I love forvo but those are book-reading pronunciations. I hear two sounds at forvo but not in the real world.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm with Mitch: I very often hear only one /ʤ/ (with maybe an initial /ʒ/) in "orange juice" among speakers. As an assiduous speaker, even I find myself linking the affricatives sometimes, as my tongue only makes one motion if I say "orange juice" quickly. I'm more careful in lecture or recording, or if there's an obvious ambiguity (which chair ~ which hair ~ which air).

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin: my reading of Mitch's comment was that he said people almost always combined them, except when they were trying very hard to enunciate clearly, not that people sometimes combined them. I certainly agree that some people pronounce *oranjuice* as a single word with one /ʤ/. But how often do people say *which impanzee*?

Comment: @Mitch - I am quite used to hearing those examples pronounced with the sound twice. That's also how I say them, and I don't enunciate overly carefully in general.

Comment: I think @PeterShor  is reading me the way I expect in that I do think that most people under most circumstances in English tend to reduce to a single affricate. (that is slightly more articulate than 'stock car' which is almost always reduced). Of course, I may be wrong but I don't believe so. As to 'which chimpanzee' I wouldn't suggest Peter's parsing, but instead 'whi chimpanzee' as the usual production. 'oran juice'. There are lots of consonant clusters that get reduced in normal speech eg wasps, masts, asks, asked, fifths. People swear they don't do, but do so in natural speech.

Comment: @Mitch: if most English speakers in most circumstances reduced them to a single affricate, I don't think they would all pronounce them with two affricates in forvo.com. There's not that much difference between book-reading pronunciations and everyday pronunciations.

Comment: @PeterShor I think there is a big difference between pronunciation of text and everyday.   There's an expectation of being articulate, on your best behavior with reading aloud.

Comment: Because they need more water and fertilizer.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is that *gemination* does not take place in complex segments. 'Affricates' are complex segments; they start off as plosives, but finish as fricatives (they have two manners of articulation).

Or because affricates are composed of two different kinds of sounds (plosives + fricatives).

We usually geminate two similar sounds when they're next to each other:

- *Bad day* -> [bæd̚.deɪ]
- *This sin* -> [ðɪsːɪn] etc.

The /d/ and /s/ can be geminated because we don't have any complex segments here.

However, when two affricates come next to each other, we get four different kinds of sounds:

- *Orange juice* -> [ɒɹɪnd͡ʒ.d͡ʒuːs]: **[d ʒ d ʒ]**
- *Which chair* -> [wɪt͡ʃ.t͡ʃeə]: **[t ʃ t ʃ]**

In case of '[continuants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuant)', the geminate is just a longer version of the continuant.

- *Hi**s z**one* -> [hɪz:əʊn]
- *So**l**e**l**y* -> [səʊlːi]

However, 'stops' don't do the same because they're obstruents. Their gemination often results in an '[unreleased stop](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release)' followed by a released one:

- *Lam**p p**ost* -> [læmp̚pʰəʊst] (not [læmppʰəʊst]).
- *Ba**d d**ay* -> [bæd̚deɪ]

Affricates can be thought of as 'stops', but with a fricative release, so if the first affricate is unreleased ([t̚] or [d̚]), their geminates are *supposed to be pronounced* (not how they're pronounced):

- [t̚t͡ʃ] and
- [d̚d͡ʒ]

that's why they can be confusing.

From *[Sounds of the Worlds Languages (1st Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0631198156)* by Peter Ladefoged:

> Geminate affricates are very clearly different from an affricate sequence, since the sequence has two stop and two frication portions, while a geminate affricate has a long stop closure followed by one fricative portion.

But he doesn't explain why they don't occur in English.

Comment: "it could be that the gemination of 'affricates' usually results in the gemination of the plosive part of the affricate rather than a geminated affricate" <--- Native speakers of English do not do this! Also *orange juice* is nearly always pronounced /ɒrɪn**ʒ dʒ**u:s/. Try it and see!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore., Right. I've updated my answer. I deleted that point. (I'm not going to address how orange juice is pronounced because the question is not about that.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find anything about *gemination of affricates in English* on the internet. Affricates share features with both stops and fricatives, both of which can geminate in English, so it's surprising that affricates don't.